# Photoshop CC video render has no sound

Tags: video, audio, dvd

On Photoshop CC 2015.0.0 I can play my video and hear the camera audio soundtrack. When I render the resultant MP4 has no sound. My movie consists of Nikon .MOV files, and some text overlays and is 35 minutes long. Render settings are shown below.

[image: Photoshop CC Render Video dialog]

What am I missing?

[Edit] Preset options shown below.
[image: Render Preset optoins.]

The "Adobe Media Encoder" drop-down also contains Photoshop Image Sequence (which will save a series of JPEGs).

Comment: There are no settings related to audio in that dialog box. What other options do you see in the dropdown menu currently set to 'Adobe Media Encoder'

Comment: @Mulvya, one other option - "Photoshop Image Sequence" - which, AFAIK generates a series of JPEGs.

Comment: Ok, I have the same options in CS6 and it works here i.e. I get audio when rendering to MP4. I suggest opening some other video with audio in CC and rendering that to MP4. Check if there's still no sound.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe released Photoshop CC 2015.0.1 this evening and it seems to have fixed the problem. (I had tried again with a short clip and couldn't get any sound.)

[image: Ps CC video render settings that produce audio.]

So, unfortunately, I don't really know what the problem was, but this patch seems to have fixed it.